# Cannot resolve scoped service from root provider even after adding that class to services

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

On an ASP.NET Core project I have the following on Startup's ConfigureServices method:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
   ...
   services.AddLiteDatabase<Database>(connectionString);
   ...
 }
```

And on Startup's Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application, IWebHostEnvironment environment) {
  ...
  application.UseLiteDatabase<DatabaseConfiguration>();
  ...
}
```

`UserLiteDatabase` calls the method `Configure` on `DatabaseConfiguration` which has:

```
IWebHostEnvironment environment = provider.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
Database database = provider.GetService<Database>();
```

I am able to get IWebHostEnvironment but I get the error when getting database:

```
Cannot resolve scoped service 'Database' from root provider.'
```

What am I missing?

**Remaining Code**

On the method `AddLiteDatabase` I have:

```
public static void AddLiteDatabase<T>(this IServiceCollection services, String connectionString) where T : LiteDatabase {
  T database = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new Object[] { connectionString });
  services.AddScoped<T>(x => database);
}
```

And the method `UseLiteDatabase` has:

```
public static void UseLiteDatabase<T>(this IApplicationBuilder builder) where T : IDatabaseConfiguration<LiteDatabase> {
  T configuration = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new Object[] { builder });
  configuration.Configure();
}
```

And the other classes are:

```
public interface IDatabaseConfiguration<T> where T : LiteDatabase {
  void Configure();
}

public class Database : LiteDatabase {
  public Database(String connection) : base (connection) { }
}

public class DatabaseConfiguration : IDatabaseConfiguration<LiteDatabase> {

  private readonly IApplicationBuilder _builder;

  public DatabaseConfiguration(IApplicationBuilder builder) {
    _builder = builder;
  }

  public void Configure() { 
    IServiceProvider provider = _builder.ApplicationServices;
    IWebHostEnvironment environment = provider.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
    Database database = provider.GetService<Database>();
    ...
  }
}
```